# I'm trying to add image in js file within innerHTML element for Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, innerhtml

When I use online links it works but when I specify the local path it doesn't load up.

**Working:** 
 
`<img src="https://test-img-url">`

**Not working:** 
`<img src="image/smile.jpg">`

Files:
`--Chrome
    |
    |-----manifeset.json
    |-----core
           |
           |--- CfCore.js
           |--- images
                  |
                  |---smile.jpg`

So I'm in CfCore.js where I'm using innerHTML: 
`e.innerHTML='<a href=#> <img src="images/smile.jpg" id="smile"> </a>'`

Also in manifest file I tried:
`"web_accessible_resources":["images/smile.jpg"]`

I found people suggesting using chrome://extensions , web_accessible_resources in manifest file and I don't find it helpful how would I code in my js file.

Answer (score 2):

`"web_accessible_resources"` in manifest.json is required, yes.

Then use `chrome.runtime.getURL` in your code:

```
e.innerHTML = '<a href=#><img src="' + 
    chrome.runtime.getURL('images/smile.jpg') + '" id="smile"></a>');
```

Or use a simple [regexp replace](https://regex101.com/r/DTOOSS/1) to insert `chrome.runtime.getURL` in relative src links automatically:

```
e.innerHTML = expandLocalSrc('<a href=#><img src="images/smile.jpg" id="smile"></a>');

function expandLocalSrc(html) {
    return html.replace(/src="([^:"]+)"/g, 'src="' + chrome.runtime.getURL('') + '$1"');
}
```

P.S. **Links are relative to manifest.json** so according to your question it's `core/images/smile.jpg` or simply move out `images` directory out of `core`.

Comment: Thank you bro ur an life saver.

Comment: So I've arrived now to another problem. 
How would I make it work with other browsers like firefox, safari. 
Since the above code only works with chrome.